# Magento Store URL

Tags: magento-1.7, url

I have installed Magento 1.7.0.2 on my server and currently my store can be viewed at myurl.com/magento.  I was hoping I could rename the magento folder to whatever I wanted to call my store, but it seems like that is not the case.

What is the best way to change the URL of your store?

Comment: after update, clear the cache under car/cache

Answer (score 3):

URL is stored in the database in the table `core_config_data`. So if you move your Magento to another directory, you also need to update the database. Open the table and search for the rows where in the "path" column you can see:

1. `web/unsecure/base_url`
2. `web/secure/base_url`

Comment: Oh no! I did this and now I cannot view my site or log into the admin panel on either /magento or /my new store url

Comment: Don't forget the trailing slash on your url.

Answer (score 1):

as the above answer states you need to update the core_config_data table within MySQL, To do this you can run the following SQL commands:

```
SELECT config_id FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
```

Take the config_id from this sql query and add to the next one:

```
UPDATE core_config_date SET value = "new store url" WHERE config_id = replace with id above
```

repeat for the base URL and you should be good to go. Depending on what cache you have enabled you may need to clear these down as well.

Comment: Oh no! I did this and now I cannot view my site or log into the admin panel on either /magento or /my new store url

Comment: Any ideas? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Just run the first SQL statement and check that the data in the value column is correct. E.g. http://www.mywebstore.com/ its important to have the http and the final forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to actually modify your DB dump prior to import and remove the var/cache and var/session directories.

So you'd first dump your DB, then use `sed` to replace URLs, then reimport.

```
sed 's#www.olddomain.com/magento#www.newdomain.com/newmagento' dbdump.sql
```

For DB dumps, we strongly recommend using this script http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quicker-dumping-of-a-magento-mysql-database-for-branching/